# Twilio video track won't properly fit to div

Tags: html, css, video-streaming, twilio, webrtc

So here I have the code for an individual to have their preview/local track added to a div onScreen while they join the room. I can get the stream fine but whenever I put it into my div it won't fit to its size properly so that its a smaller stream in the bottom corner of the screen.

div .css

```
#localMediaTrackDiv{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    position: absolute;
    border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

the react/html

```
componentWillMount(){
    // Request audio and video tracks
    createLocalVideoTrack({audio: false, video: { width: 250 } }).then(track => {
        var localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('localMediaTrack');
        localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
    });
}

<div id='localMediaTrackDiv'>
    <div id='localMediaTrack'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the css width on the `<video />` element, like this:

```
#localMediaTrackDiv video{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}
```

That has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call `createLocalVideoTrack` you pass the option of `width: 250` however your CSS set the width of the `#localMediaTrackDiv` to `200px`. Try making those the same figure.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. (I am dealing with the exact same issue)

Comment: @cammil it might be easier to ask a new question with your circumstances, because I'm not sure how to create a new answer. Let me know if you do create a new question and I'll take a look.

Comment: You can just edit your answer? It is the exact same question. Stackoverflow doesn't like duplicates. I have tried making the widths the same in css and as options to `createLocalVideoTrack`, but that does not work. I have tried one, but leaving the other out. That doesn't work either. It seems the width is always the same, about 640px I reckon.

Comment: Sorry, it's quite the context switch to deal with an answer I wrote 2 years ago! I think the issue here may be that you are applying the CSS to the containing div and not the `<video>` itself. Try applying the width to  `localMediaTrack > video`.

Comment: Yep I noticed that shortly after, and have added an answer. Thanks for the support though!